# nagios error 127: ./check_icmp: No such file or directory (some plugins won't execute)

Tags: linux, nagios, opsview

I'm running opsview (nagios) and 1 slave server doesn't execute some plugins correctly

```
Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing
```

when I execute the plugin manually it says

```
./check_icmp
bash: ./check_icmp: No such file or directory
```

on the master and other slaves it's working when executing the plugins

I have been googling and trying stuff for days now but can't get it working

edit:solved by Kyle Brandt (see comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that the file doesn't have executable permissions.  What user are you running it as?  If the file is owned by the user or a group the user is in, if there are no executable permissions for the user, then even if 'all' has executable permissions, the user still won't be able to run it.

So for instance, if it is owned by the user Nagios, but there the file doesn't have executable permission for user, then you will get that error, even if file is executable by all / others:

```
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: ~/scrap] ls -l true.pl                                                                                                <24252@6:17>
-rw-rw-r-x 1 kbrandt kbrandt 603 2009-04-14 13:17 true.pl
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: ~/scrap] ./true.pl                                                                                                   
zsh: permission denied: ./true.pl
```

The same goes for groups.  If a file were owned by the user 'Joe' and the group 'Nagios', and user kbrandt who is a member of group Nagios tried to run it, if the group column doesn't have executable permission, kbrandt won't be able to run it.

---

**Update after long Comment Thread:**
Have you tried Recompiling the plug-ins on that machine?

> thats it! the files get copied from
>   another (intel machine) automatically
>   by opsview on this one! compiling
>   plugins from source worked

Comment: ls -alh|grep icmp:
 -r-sr-x--x 1 root nagios 32K 2009-08-24 15:28 check_icmp
running chmod 777 won't work either
also used chmod +s etc. whatever I do it wont run

Comment: You have setuid set on it, is the filesystem mounted with nosuid option?  The mount command will show you the mount options.

Comment: also it would not generate the error message "No such file or directory" but "permission denied"

Comment: "is the filesystem mounted with nosuid option?" 
(rw,relatime)

Comment: And all the directories leading up the one that has the plugin have search (x) permission? For instance, /foo/bar/check_icmp , both foo and bar have +x ?

Comment: Also what does 'file check_icmp' return?

Comment: yes, I dont think its a permissions

Comment: check_icmp: setuid setgid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

Comment: Looks right if it is a 32 bit system, have you tried recompiling the plugins on that machine?

Comment: system mounted "noexec"?

Comment: Also, are you using any sort of extensions, ie extended attributes, ACLs, SELinux ?

Comment: thats it! the files get copied from another (intel machine) automatically by opsview on this one! compiling plugins from source worked!!